# What does smooth mean here?

Tags: meaning, collocations

A non-native English speaker told me:

> Hope you are smooth in your plan.

What does it mean?

The only thing I found in [Longman](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/smooth) dictionary is:

> someone who is smooth is polite, confident, and relaxed, but is often not sincere

This meaning does not make sense here.

Comment: Where was this sentence?? Context helps.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If that was said by a non-native speaker, it sounds like they are hoping you plan **goes smoothly**, meaning you don't experience any bumps (problems) executing the plan.

For clarity, this is not how a native speaker would express this, but it's easily understandable.

It's similar to saying

> They run a smooth operation.

meaning things just work without problems or complications.

Comment: is **goes smoothly** common by native speakers?

Comment: @Stephen Yes, it sounds perfectly natural to say "I hope the plan goes smoothly."  Common?  Well, people say it.  Don't really know how much ;)

Comment: It's worth pointing out that although this is almost certainly the right answer, the actual sentence "Hope you are smooth in your plan." is ungrammatical to the point where it's barely understandable.

Comment: @boatseller for posterity I would edit to highlight the fact that "smooth in your plan" is not idiomatic English, and most native speakers would be at least mildly confused just like OP.

Answer (score 2):

There is an idiom, **smooth in your shoes**, which means to be happy and at ease and confident.

Without further context, my guess would be that this is a use of "to be smooth in {something}", which means to be content, confident, and at ease with {something}.

"I hope you have thought your plan through and are happy with it and confident that it is going to work."

However, it could just as easily be an unidiomatic attempt at "I hope your plan is going smoothly".

Comment: Where is "smooth in your shoes" used? I don't think I've heard it before in AusEng.

Comment: I've also never heard this in en-US.

Comment: Nor in British English.

Comment: I used to work with a fellow from Fiji who used it of people who were suave, easygoing, and confident, at home in almost any situation.  I assumed it was an Aussie idiom.

Comment: Not AusE.  If it was Australian it would be 'smooth in your thongs'   :-)

Comment: This is not an idiom. "Smooth in your shoes" only returns 6 results on Google. Maybe you're thinking of "comfortable in your own skin".

Comment: Perhaps this is a direct translation of a Fiji-an idiom?

Comment: @G. Ann - SonarSource Team   That's possible. It made such immediate sense to me in context, I figured it was an Aussie or Kiwi version of "cool cat" talk.  Even now I can easily imagine Murray Hewitt of *Flight of the Conchords* saying "You have to be smooth in your shoes, Jemaine".